# Set different hyperref color inside frame of tcolorbox

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, color, tcolorbox

I currently have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=blue}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{testenv}{
  \tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=blue!10!white,coltext=NavyBlue,%
    fonttitle=\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue!10!white}}
}

\begin{document}

\section{test\label{sec:test}}

Referring to \ref{sec:test} outside of tcolorbox.

\begin{testenv}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Referring to \ref{sec:test} in the tcolorbox frame]
Referring to \ref{sec:test} inside of tcolorbox.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{testenv}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

I would like the "1" in the text "Referring to 1 in the tcolorbox frame" to be the same colour as the rest of the frame text `(blue!10!white)`. If possible, I would prefer not change the hyperlink text colour globally or the colour of the `tcolorbox` frame background.

I have tried setting

```
fonttitle=\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue!10!white}
```

in the preamble, but this hasn't worked. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not use `\url`s but `\ref`s, thus `linkcolor` instead of `urlcolor` must be changed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=blue}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{testenv}{
 \tcbset{colframe=blue!75!black,colback=blue!10!white,coltext=NavyBlue,%
   fonttitle=\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue!10!white}}% linkcolor instead of urlcolor!
}

\begin{document}

\section{test\label{sec:test}}

Referring to \ref{sec:test} outside of tcolorbox.

\begin{testenv}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Referring to \ref{sec:test} in the tcolorbox frame]
Referring to {\hypersetup{linkcolor=NavyBlue}\ref{sec:test}} %
% if you want to change the color here, too.
inside of tcolorbox.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{testenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ictl: No problem, with the different types of "links" it is easy to get confused.

Comment: `fonttitle=\hypersetup{linkcolor=white,urlcolor=white}` doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: @71GA: There is no url in the MWE, therefore `urlcolor=white` does not have any visible effect. It neither triggers an error message when I compile the MWE. Could you post a MWE as new question?